# Custom tab not visible

Tags: custom-object, tab

I'm working in a PE org.
I have added a new custom object and a tab (I have many other custom tabs as well). I have added the tab to one of the custom app I have but unlike all my other custom objects/tabs this one does not appear on and I cannot see it.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

It may be a confirmation issue or may that profile does not have permission.

Try to delete that tab and recreate again

Comment: There are no profiles because it's a professional edition. I tried deleting and recreating the tab but still it does not show